# Taking values from a Ruby array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
a = [{"Key1"=>"Value1", "Key2"=>"Value2"}, 
     {"Key1"=>"Value3", "Key2"=>"Value4"},
     {"Key1"=>"Value5", "Key2"=>"Value6"}]
```

Basically I am trying to get an output with only values and not any keys. Something like this

```
['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5', 'Value6']
```

Here is the code which I tried. As `key1` and `key2` are the same, I stored both the keys in an array....

```
k = ["key1", "key2"]
for i in 0..a.length  
  k.each do |key_to_delete| 
    a[i].delete key_to_delete unless a[i].nil?
  end 
end
```

However, this removes all values and I get an empty array. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually you don't have a ruby hash in a, you have an array of hashes in a.

Comment: do you want an array of arrays, or just a single array of all the values?

Comment: Maybe you want this?
[["Value1", "Value2"], ["Value3", "Value4"], ["Value5", "Value6"]]
(Just modify Ilya's answer to use `map` instead of `flat_map`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable#flat_map` and fetch values from each hash:

```
a.flat_map(&:values)
=> ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5", "Value6"]
```

This is an answer on the original question.

Comment: Or even more shorter: `a.flat_map(&:values)`

Comment: Perfect and this is the output I wanted. Thanks a lot for your lightning response :)

Comment: @TGR this is basically the output you had in your original question, why did you change it?

Comment: @Stefan I was little confused. Apols for confusion. I am perfectly fine with llya & Sergil's output